# Unix script to search recursively to find ultimate parent in a delimited file

Tags: unix, ksh

I am looking for help to write a **Korn** shell script to find the top manager in a pipe delimited file. Some recursive logic.

Input is something like below:

```
DATE         EMPID      MGRID      MGRNAME    EMPNAME   PROJID
01-01-2014   111111     9999999    ABC        XYZ1      1     
01-01-2014   111112     9999998    ABD        XYZ2      2     
01-01-2014   111113     9999997    ACE        XYZ3      3     
02-01-2014   9999999    7777777    ZZZX1      ABC       4     
03-01-2014   7777777    7777778    ZZZY1      ZZZX1     5     
03-02-2014   7777778    6666666    ZZZY2      ZZZY1     6     
04-02-2014   7777778    6666667    ZZY3       ZZZY1     7     
04-08-2014   9999997    6666665    ZXX1       ACE       11
```

My output should be like this:

```
EMPID       MGRID       MGRNAME     EMPNAME     PROJID                                                   
111111      6666667     ZZY3        XYZ1        7  --  latest MGRID, MGRNAME and 
                                                        PROJID based on date    
111112      9999998     ABD         XYZ2        2   -- No change as MGRID does 
                                                       not exist in EMPID column 
111113      6666665     ZXX1        XYZ3        11  -- should get new MGRID, 
                                                        MGRNAME and PROJID          
9999999     6666666     ZZZY2       ABC         6  -- should get new MGRID, 
                                                       MGRNAME and PROJID           
7777777     6666666     ZZZY2       ZZZX1       6  -- should get new MGRID, 
                                                       MGRNAME and PROJID           
7777778     6666666     ZZZY2       ZZZY1       6  -- No change as MGRID does 
                                                      not exist in EMPID column  
7777778     6666667     ZZY3        ZZZY1       7  -- No change as MGRID does 
                                                      not exist in EMPID column  
9999997     6666665     ZXX1        ACE         11  -- No change as MGRID does 
                                                      not exist in EMPID column.
```

Any help is highly appreciated.-

Comment: What is your attempt so far? (this is not a free coding service).  If ksh is a requirement, you should add `ksh` as tag. Where are the pipes in your 'pipe delimited file'? You could read the file into an 'associative array` (or array for each column, with EMPID as key)  and then walk  through that list, identifying the manager.

Comment: It's unusual to have employee ID 7777778 associated with two managers, 6666666 and 6666667.  And neither of those manager IDs appears in the data.  Confusing.

Comment: your output contains comments that mention the date column, but you've provided no instructions/logic for how the date is used to determine your final result; I recommend you take a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and then come back and update your question accordingly